# Collection change security with yield return statements

Tags: c#, .net, yield-return

Using yield return Statements I always wonder wheter to implement a version count:

```
private IEnumerator<string> GetStrings()
{
    int initialVersion = _version; // Where _version is incremented everytime the list changes
    foreach(string s in _listInternal)
    {
        if (initialVersion != _version)
            throw ...;
        yield return s; 
    }
}
```

foreach(string s in _listInternal) would catch this in this case of course, but if I do not use a collection or list as source, can there be problems?

If i change the collection that creates the enumerator it normally uses this _version field to protect itself from being changed while an iterator iterates throug the items. This is also a Problem when multiple threads work on it.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Could you please specify it better?

Comment: Is this a thread safety question?

Comment: @aj.toulan Potentially, but not usually.  Generally it's a single thread that mutates the underlying colleciton in the body of a foreach loop, something like `foreach(var item in list) list.Remove(item);`.

Comment: I usually use this in that case. list.RemoveAll(x => x.ShouldDelete); Where ShouldDelete is a bool property in the type of list you are manipulating. I believe one can also write this as list.RemoveAll(ShouldDelete);

Comment: @aj.toulan Yes, that is one way of solving that particular problem without generating this error; I was giving an example of improperly written code that *should* throw this exception if used, with the expectation that the caller alter their code to something more along the lines of what you have.  I was also demonstrating that the improperly written code need not be (and likely won't be) multithreaded.

Comment: Understood. My point was that linq will solve any of the problems surrounding this for you and will also throw the appropriate exceptions.

Comment: @aj.toulan You're not using LINQ there, you're using a method of `List`.  LINQ is for querying data, not for manipulating collections, so no, it doesn't provide tools for manipulating collections.

Comment: You're right, I miss spoke. They are List methods. So even though you have already admitted that this is bad practice, if you change the what is in the list when you enumerate over it, wont it throw an ArgumentNullException in the action that is passed in?

Comment: @aj.toulan The point is that you should be throwing an exception when something wrong is being done.  It's a *feature* that the iterator actually yells at you when you abuse it, rather than just silently moving along and not complaining despite the fact that your results are almost certainly going to be completely messed up.  And if you do do it, it won't throw an `ArgumentNullException`, it will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. It will do so because the list's iterator has code *exactly like this example*. If you are using a collection without that feature, *you* need to provide it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation, I really do appreciate it. I think I understand now. I'm still unsure if I would use a yield return this way. Maybe in the future I'll change my mind :D

Comment: May someone tell me the reason for the downvotes, please?!

Comment: It may be that you did not explain yourself thoroughly. I certainly didn't understand what you were doing, just reading the title and the explanation. You could also have included a more detailed code example. Servy had done this kind of thing before, which is why he knew what you meant. Questions should be understandable to anyone. Also they may have down voted before you edited your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need, assuming `_listInternal` is in fact a `List<T>`.  The `List` enumerator already implements this functionality; its enumerator will throw an exception if you mutate the collection while iterating it, and that exception will propagate up through your iterator block.

If your iterator block is based on an underlying collection that doesn't already have this behavior, or there is mutable state besides just some underlying collection that you use, but that cannot change, then you may want to use this pattern, yes.

Of course, in order to be *able* to implement this pattern you need to have some way of incrementing the version number when the underlying data is changed.  Sometimes, if you're using a collection you don't have control over the code for, you just can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will never need to use a version for a yield return, they should be considered atomic.

Comment: It's entirely appropriate to want the iterator to throw an exception when the underlying data the iterator is based on changes during enumeration.  It's a fairly common pattern used in many places, saying you'll never need it simply isn't true.

Comment: Correct, but I think what I said still stands. I took this question as a typical use case. I was not aware that throwing an exception in an enumerable block was common practice. I especially would not expect this from a get method. Typically yield returns are used when processing needs to be distributed, segmented or the enumerable is of an unknowable length (such as an infinite set). I did not see the author manipulating the set in the foreach either. I thought this was bad practice considering you're changing the set in a foreach within itself. Linq has solutions for these issues.

Comment: You're asserting that this should never be done.  That's completely untrue.  There are situations where it is entirely appropriate to do this, so no, what you said *shouldn't* stand.  You should throw an exception from an iterator block when you have come across an exceptional problem that prevents enumeration of the sequence; a corrupted underlying data source most certainly qualifies.  Yielding bad data instead of throwing would be much worse.  As for the use of and iterator block here; it's just an example; including the actual work is unnecessary and would just be distracting.

Comment: "I thought this was bad practice considering you're changing the set in a foreach within itself."  Yes it is; which is why you should throw an exception if you find yourself in that position, as an iterator, to indicate to the developer that they're doing something wrong, rather than ignoring the problem and trying to sweep it under the rug.  "Linq has solutions for these issues."  No it doesn't.  It will happily let you modify an underlying collection while enumerating it.  If you would like to prevent users of your iterator from doing that, you need to do it yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood me with that last part, I think that's irrelevant now. "Yielding bad data instead of throwing would be much worse." Yes, but if you're data is corrupt and it's gotten to a yield return, I'm not sure if you're following separation of concerns. There should be a data layer before it can be accessed.

Comment: Removing an item from an underlying collection is a perfectly acceptable operation for that collection; the collection itself is not corrupted, it is only the iterator that has been corrupted, because there are all sorts of very weird problems that can happen when you try to iterate over a collection that is being modified.  It is the iterator that has been corrupted, so it is the iterator that should be throwing the exception.

Comment: I thought you were saying that the data inside the collection could be corrupt. Saying that the iterator is corrupt makes more sense, I've experienced this before. I still think that the exception should be thrown by the object within the collection. That object should be responsible for it's own error detection logic.